# What is a nicer alternative to a namedtuples _replace?

Tags: python, namedtuple

Take this code:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> parts = urlparse.urlparse('http://docs.python.org/library/')
>>> parts = parts._replace(path='/3.0'+parts.path)
```

`parts._replace works` but as it is an underscored method, it's supposed to be internal, and not used. Is there an alternative? I don't want to do:

```
>>> parts = parts[:2] + ('/3.0'+parts.path,) + parts[3:]
```

Because that makes it an ordinary tuple, and not a namedtuple, and doing:

```
>>> parts = namedtuple(scheme=parts.scheme, netloc=parts.netloc, etc etc)
```

is kinda stupid. :)

Ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason methods of `namedtuple` start with an initial underscore is only to prevent name collisions. They [should not be considered to be for internal use only](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> To prevent conflicts with field names, the method and attribute names start with an underscore.

Comment: AFAIK there never was a PEP for `namedtuple`, where one could argue that *suffixing* an underscore would be more appropriate (à la `class_`) just to avoid such misunderstandings.

Comment: Suffixing may well have been a better choice though it would not work well with the rename=True option.  FWIW, the namedtuple code was extensively reviewed and discussed prior to release.  Building the recipe was a community effort (see http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/ ) and it underwent further revision and review on python-dev.