# Python namedtuple T._make(iterable) vs T(* iterable)

Tags: python, namedtuple

Minor question: I don't understand why Python's namedtuple types have a _make() function. As far as I can tell, if T is a type created with namedtuple, then

```
T._make(iterable)    and    T(* iterable)
```

are the same thing. So why have a _make() function? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

It may be useful to have a function that does the same as `T(*iterable)`. Consider this:

```
a = namedtuple('a', 'x, y')
b = [(x, x) for x in xrange(10)]
map(a._make, b)
```

Sure, you could also do:

```
[a(*x) for x in b]
```

but this correspondence to functions happens in other places, like the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions). This is just speculation though, I don't know if that is the rationale for `_make`.

**EDIT**: I found some more information on this; following a link in [a previous Stack Overflow question, regarding the reason for the underscore in namedtuple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2213108/1081569), I read [a page](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/) that states:

> The inspiration for the _make() classmethod came from Robin Becker and
>   Giovanni Bajo who pointed-out an important class of use cases where
>   existing sequences need to be cast to named tuples.